# How to pan whole screen (not just up to edittext) on soft keyboard showing?

Tags: android, android-layout

my layout is structured like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>

 <ScrollView>
 </ScrollView>

 <LinearLayout>
    <EditText/>
    <ListView/>
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Android manifest specifies adjustPan for the activity. However, when the keyboard shows, only the content up until the EditText is pushed up, and the keyboard covers the listview. Is there any way for the keyboard not to hide the listview?

**EDIT:**
adjustResize didnt work, it just hid the edit text, together with the listview.

Comment: you can manually set the position of layout when key board appears but it become complex because you need to make this for all device competeble.

Comment: Try this :  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"